# TFS 2012 Disable Multiple Check-out not working

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I would like to disable multiple check-outs for our TFS projects. Here is how I expect it to work:

1. Bob checks out File1.cs.
2. Joe double-clicks on File1.cs in his Visual Studio Solution Explorer and tries to modify it buts sees an error message saying that someone already has that file checked-out so he cannot check it out.

I've tried setting it up like this in Visual Studio for both Bob and Joe:

1. Within **Team->Team Project Collection Settings->Source Control...->Workspace Settings Tab** I changed the default workspace type from "Local (recommended)" to "Server".
2. Within **Team->Team Project Settings->Source Control...->Check-out Settings Tab** I changed **Enable multiple check-out** to be unchecked.
3. Within **Source Control Explorer->Workspace Combobox->Workspaces...->Edit...->Advanced->Location** I changed "Local" to "Server".

Still, however, Bob and Joe can both check-out the same file at the same time. Is there some other configurations options that need to be set?

Comment: You performed step 3 for both Bob and Joe's existing workspaces?

Comment: Thank you Edward! It turned out that one of them hadn't changed that option from Local to Server. It works now.

Comment: This issue here is how do we CONTROL this option from TFS not the clients machine.  I want to config and control this Server config and push it down to any machine pulling code from this project.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue (as pointed out by Edward Thomson) was that step 3 had not been performed on all of the users' workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can also uncheck **Enable file merging and multiple checkout** in **Team Project Collection Settings**.

But you have to do this to any type of file you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252452(v=vs.100).aspx