# Change Default Check-out mode in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfvc

When we want to check out a file in VS 2013 this window would show:

[image]

I want to change this setting and every time a user wants to check out a file `Lock type` set to `Check In`.How I can do this?

thanks

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014746/tfs-2012-disable-multiple-check-out-not-working

Comment: **Why** on earth do you want to do that? Exclusive locking is absolutely evil.

Comment: Some times it is angel.Imagine that I edit a function and add some code and my friend also add some code to that function.When I want to chech in my changes,occure a conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done this way:

Source Control Explorer -> Workspaces

select Workspaces, Then Edit , Then Advanced -> Change Location to **Server**