# team foundation server multiple check outs disabled but still possible

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I use Team Foundation Server for Source Control and in my Visual Studio I unckeckd the Option: "Multiple Check Out".

But when I check out a file and modify it another user can still check out the same file and also modify it.

What went wrong??

Comment: Are you using a local workspace?

Comment: Where did you uncheck the "Multiple checkout"? At the TFS configuration or just in your Visual Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS 2012 Disable Multiple Check-out not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014746/tfs-2012-disable-multiple-check-out-not-working)

Comment: I strongly recommend enabling multiple check-outs. It's incredibly painful to deal with not being able to work on something because someone else checked a file out and went to lunch.

Comment: I unchecked the "Multiple checkout" in Visual Studio.Did not found any other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to look at this issue then you are probably not checking in enough. Its a workflow and not tool change that is required.

TFS only supports the single checkout model if all users are using Server Workspaces. The default changed in 2012 to Local Workspaces which does not support this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx

Check out the MSDN documentation for how to change workspace modes.

Comment: Thanks. What is this about with the "server workspace" ? I have a Server on that TFS is installed. In Visual Studio I connect to that server and download all Projects to a local path.  How do I work with "server workspace"?  And will it affect the way files are downloaded to the developers?

Comment: Added link to full documentation