# Stop multiple users from checking out file in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a setting in visual studio online that I can set to not allow multiple check out?  I have seen where you can set the local visual studio to user server for the workspace, but can that be set at the project level on the visualstudio.com site.

Comment: Multiple check-out is a godsend. Don't turn it off.

Comment: We are a very small group and there is no reason more than one of us should be working on the same file at the same time, and I find it easier to not use the merge, and we have grown use to having thins exclusively checked out.  That being said if we find our selves constantly asking for files to check in then we may turn it back on.    I was hoping there was a way to set this in one place, that way it would be easier to change in the future quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with Git or if you are using the default Local Workspaces in TFVC. If you are using Server Workspaces (the one where every file is read only u till checkout) then you can disable multi-checkout for all files or only certain extensions in the same way as TFS.

[TFS 2012 Disable Multiple Check-out not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014746/tfs-2012-disable-multiple-check-out-not-working)

Comment: I concur.  
To achieve this you have to use Server Workspaces and TFVC not GIT, but once you've set it up it behaves as expected