# Team Foundation Server 2013 : Workspace Change from Local to Server

Tags: visual-studio-2013

We have got an implementation of TFS 2013 and the Visual Studio is configured to work with TFS 2013. Until recently when the developers are working on separate project everything went on smoothly.

Now when multiple developers are working on a single project, there is a problem of Multiple Check outs for the same file. The fact is Visual Studio is configured to work with Local Workspaces and hence the Multiple Checkouts. I tried to change the workspace from Local to Server by following the instructions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014746/tfs-2012-disable-multiple-check-out-not-working).

However, the developers now face an error (TF14098: Access Denied: User *username* needs PendChange, Lock permission(s) for *$/myproject/file.aspx*) when trying to checkout.

Itreid searching for this error on the internet but could not resolve this nor could I find any resolution for this.

Help is very much awaited and appreciated on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble with permissions. Check if any the group you are the member is denied for PendingChange and lock or its directly denied for you. Note in TFS permissions, **Deny always takes precedence**. You must make sure your users and all the groups your users belong to have the allow permissions of PendingChange and lock in the project.

You can use the command `Tf perm` to check what are the security permissions for this project . Navigate to the project location and enter it. This will basically tell you list of all users/groups with their permission. Then change the security in web access.

Comment: I have executed 'tf perm' for the user as 'tf perm /user:_username_'. The output shows, 'Server Item:$/<Inherit: No>' for the root and for the other team projects it shows 'Server Item: $/_TeamProjectName_ <Inherit: Yes> There are no permissions set for this item.'

Comment: This means you were not deliberately setting permissions for the user .You can right click your project in source control, selcect Advance→Secruity. In the pop-up window, make sure your team group including the developers such as Contributors have the allow permissions or inherit allow(which inherit from team project collection) for lock, check out and so on...

Comment: thanks for the comment. I checked in source control as specified and found that contributors have Lock Permissions set to Deny.  I have changed it to allow. And I will check over the weekend, if I am able to multiple checkout disabling. Will post the result by Monday.

Comment: I have checked this over th eweeked and it worked to the requirement. Thanks.